# How to add one more SID for Database instance? Oracle

Tags: oracle, sid

I want to add one more SID for database? How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  An Oracle database has a single SID.  You can [create multiple service names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/rac.102/b28759/configwlm.htm#CACFEADG) for a database.  I'm not sure why you would want to have multiple SIDs but I suspect that whatever you want to do you can do by using service names.

Comment: Really me need change current SID in db to new SID. I used Oracle 11g and in him not included feature service names, maybe need apply patch, but easier change SID, how to do change SID? Thanks!

Comment: @artzub - Service names have been supported for quite some time, any version of 11g uses service names.  Based on this comment, you really want to change the one and only SID of your database.  You don't want to add a second SID as you asked in your question, correct?

Comment: Correct! I want change current SID to new SID, but question about multiple SIDs interesting for experience =)